# Rename some keys in an object

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, ecmascript-6, key-value

I have an object with multiple keys and values.

I only want to rename some of the keys and not all. With what I do, it is not returning the rest of the key-value pairs in the object:

```js
data = {key1: "value1", key2: "value2", key3: "value3", key4: "value4"}; 

keyMap = {key1: "firstkey", key2: "secondkey"};

mappedData = Object.keys(keyMap).reduce((obj,k) => Object.assign(obj, { [keyMap[k]]: data[k] }),{});

console.log(mappedData);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

How do I get back:

```
{
  firstkey: "value1",
  secondkey: "value2",
  key3: "value3", 
  key4: "value4"
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could get the entries and replace the keys by checking `keyMap` and get either the new or take the old key.

```js
let data =  { key1: "value1", key2: "value2", key3: "value3", key4: "value4" }; 
    keyMap = { key1: "firstkey", key2: "secondkey" },
    mappedData = Object.fromEntries(
        Object
            .entries(data)
            .map(([key, value]) => [key in keyMap ? keyMap[key] : key, value])
    );

console.log(mappedData);
```

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps something like this:

```js
const changeKeys = (keyMap) => (obj) =>
  Object .fromEntries (Object .entries (obj) .map (([k, v]) => [keyMap[k] || k, v]))

const data = {key1: "value1", key2: "value2", key3: "value3", key4: "value4"}; 
const keyMap = {key1: "firstkey", key2: "secondkey"};

console .log(
  changeKeys (keyMap) (data)
)
```

Using `Object.entries` and `Object.fromEntries` with a `map` or other transform in between solves all sorts of Object manipulation problems.

If [`Object.fromEntries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries) is [not available](https://caniuse.com/#search=fromEntries) for your environment, it's easy to shim.

Comment: Nina's use of `in` would be better if you ever need to map a key to the empty string.

Answer (score 2):

Here's your code with a little update:

```
data = {key1: "value1", key2: "value2", key3: "value3", key4: "value4"}; 

keyMap = {key1: "firstkey", key2: "secondkey"};

mappedData = Object.keys(data).reduce((obj,k) => Object.assign(obj, { [keyMap[k] || k]: data[k] }),{});

console.log(mappedData);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do it in one pass with a for loop

```js
data = {key1: "value1", key2: "value2", key3: "value3", key4: "value4"}; 

keyMap = {key1: "firstkey", key2: "secondkey"};

const isDefined = x => typeof x !== 'undefined'

const renameKeys = o => {
  const newObj = {}
  for (const key in o) {
    if (isDefined(keyMap[key])) {
      newObj[keyMap[key]] = o[key]
    } else {
      newObj[key] = o[key]
    }
  }
  return newObj
}

console.log(
  renameKeys(data)
)
```

Answer (score 1):

I would loop over the data and see if a key exists. If it does use it, if not use the original key.

```js
var data = {
  key1: "value1",
  key2: "value2",
  key3: "value3",
  key4: "value4"
};

var keyMap = {
  key1: "firstkey",
  key2: "secondkey"
};


const updated = Object.entries(data).reduce((obj, [key, value]) => {
  const updatedKey = keyMap[key] || key
  obj[updatedKey] = value
  return obj
}, {})

console.log(updated);
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your accumulator in your `reduce` function is a new, empty object, and you're only iterating over the keys you want to change.

There are a lot of ways to do what you're trying to do. I personally find `reduce` confusing to parse, so I'd skip that and do something like this:

```js
const data = {key1: "value1", key2: "value2", key3: "value3", key4: "value4"}; 

const keyMap = {key1: "firstkey", key2: "secondkey"};

const mappedData = {};
for(const key of Object.keys(data)){
  // Use the renamed key if it exists, else fall back on the original key
  mappedData[ keyMap[key] || key ] = data[ key ];
}

console.log(mappedData);
```

You could apply the same sort of logic to the `reduce` if you really wanted to do it that way, by iterating over the original data instead of the keymap:

```js
const data = {key1: "value1", key2: "value2", key3: "value3", key4: "value4"}; 

const keyMap = {key1: "firstkey", key2: "secondkey"};

mappedData = Object.keys(data).reduce((obj,k) => Object.assign(obj, { [keyMap[k] || k]: data[k] }),{});

console.log(mappedData);
```